# WooCommerce: Product variations that don't require all options selected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

So I thought I could figure this out in a fairly straightforward manner, but it has been utterly perplexing me: I'm setting up a store to sell fonts. These fonts are available in a variety of licenses that affect the price: For example:

- **Desktop**

  - 1-5 Users
  - 6-10 Users
  - 10+ Users
- **Web**

  - 1 Domain
  - Up to 5 Domains
  - Up to 10 Domains

...etc. As the store is selling packs & collections as well as individual weights & styles, all of these variations are customisable with regards to their price, attached files, etc. Plus, due to the licensing of some typefaces, not all are available under the same licenses.

**The issue:** If a user selects `Desktop: 1-5 Users`, then they *definitely* shouldn't be required to select a Web license. However, if I try to add a font to my cart with just `Desktop: 1-5 Users` selected and no `Web` selection, it fails.

In the backend I currently have all `Desktop` variations set to 'Any Web...' and vice versa, but it doesn't make any difference.

As an addendum to this, I experimented with using jQuery to set any unchosen selection's value to 'null'; so, user selects `Desktop: 1-5 Users`; `Web` dropdown is automatically hidden and value set to 'null'. This works (sort of) insofar as the product will get added to the cart, but it appears as:

**Fontname**

- Desktop: *1-5 Users*
- Web: *null*

Again, I can edit the template in `/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` to not display the `null` attribute on the site, but it still appears in emails, in the order on the backend, etc. Ideally I want a way to simply not have *all* license attributes being selected as a prerequisite of adding a font  to the cart.

Hopefully I am just not seeing the wood for the trees here and missing something blindingly obvious and simple.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to split the licenses into two separate products - web and desktop.

Or perhaps you could chain or combine them using one of the Woothemes [product grouping extensions](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/chained-products-vs-product-bundles-vs-force-sells-vs-grouped-products/). Alternatively, the [Extra Product Options](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619) extension could be suitable to your needs. The Extra product options adds additional metadata to each order, you can use conditional logic on the product page to help guide a user to the best product/price match.

Good luck! eCommerce is harder than it looks!

Answer (score 0):

Think about adding as default:

- no web licence
- no dekstop licence

It will produce:

### Desktop

- No desktop
- 1-5 Users
- 6-10 Users
- 10+ Users

### Web

- No web
- 1 Domain
- Up to 5 Domains
- Up to 10 Domains

In woocommerce you can select no web/desktop as default variation and uncheck visible on product page.

Similar future can be achived by PHP code by hooking to woocommerce filters, but in my opinion using product configuration is much more elegant.

Comment: This was a _long_ time ago, but I'm almost certain that this is something I tried and did not work as expected. Regardless, the original project is long gone now.